# Keeping price-by-day statistics in a Redis DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have **offers** that I receive from service providers and I need to build statistics based on:

- offer **start date**
- offer **duration**
- offer **destination**
- offer **price**

Basically it will be used to build a date-price diagram for a particular destination and duration.

What are the ways you would recommend to store it in a Redis DB?

[image: How it should look in the end]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making keys of type `Sorted Set`.

- Each *key* is a combination of destination and duration, such as `offer:newyork:7`.
- Each *member* (inside a key) contains the *value* of the price, and a *score* of date (as a [Unix time](http://redis.io/commands/time)).

In such way, you can query a particular destination and duration that you know beforehand (another option, partially acceptable but depends - fetching available keys via `KEYS` command), and get all offers sorted by the date (`ZRANGEBYSCORE ... WITHSCORES`).

Comment: The problem with **Sorted Sets** is that the **value** must be unique. And it is highly probable that you'd have two equal prices for two different dates. Any thoughts?

Comment: So switch them, value:date, score:price. But then you'll need to get all members and sort them locally.

Comment: Is it bad to use KEYS command and not using sets at all? Will it be slower? I.e. offer:ny -> offer:ny:7 -> offer:ny:7:2012-04-05

Comment: The statistics are going to be built for a two-week period for instance so it would be really nice to be able to get only a portion by date.

Comment: the key names isn't the native Redis way to go, although it really depends on your concrete use. If you can clearly partition your data and "know what you're looking for" so querying `KEYS` won't have Redis scan all of your keys (O(n) operation) then it's OK.